# C# string to sentence

Tags: c#, string

Is there a way to convert string without spaces to a proper sentence??
E.g. "WhoAmI" needs to be converted to "Who Am I"

Comment: What about whoamI ?, Do you want it to be converted again to who am I ?

Answer (score 8):

A regex replacement would do this, if you're *just* talking about inserting a space before each capital letter:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = "WhoAmI";
        var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\p{Lu}", " $0").TrimStart();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

However, I suspect there will be significant corner cases. Note that the above uses `\p{Lu}` instead of just `[A-Z]` to cope with non-ASCII capital letters; you may find `A-Z` simpler if you only need to deal with ASCII. The `TrimStart()` call is to remove the leading space you'd get otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If every word in the string is starting with uppercase you may just convert each part that is starting with uppercase to a space separated string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ

```
string words = "WhoAmI";
string sentence = String.Concat(words.Select(letter => Char.IsUpper(letter) ? " " + letter 
                                    : letter.ToString()))
                                    .TrimStart();
```